# How can I mouldproof a conservatory?

Tags: mold

We bought a small conservatory a few years ago.  Despite following all the available advice (minimising condensation, cleaning regularly, etc...) mould still accumulates in the corners.

What can I do that would make it impossible for mould to grow in the conservatory?  For example, are there any coatings I could have applied?

NOTE:  I'm not asking about an on-going process that we'd have to keep doing, nor about something we could do that would only *decrease* the amount of mould.  I want that mould gone.  Dead.  FOREVER.

(In case it makes a difference, we're in the UK)

Comment: To me that means you have a lot of windows. have you tried using a dehumidifier to reduce the condensation on the windows? With moisture comes mold. eliminate the moisture and you eliminate the mould.

Comment: Yeah, we’re running a dehumidifier 24/7. It might be helping a bit, but it’s not noticeable.